# Methods for solving $4t^2x''+x=at^n$, where $n\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a\in\mathbb{C}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking for a method to find solutions to the differential equation
$$4t^2x''+x=at^n,$$
where $n$ is a real number and $a$ is complex. This is a variation of the second-order Cauchy-Euler differential equation $\alpha t^2x''+\beta tx'+\gamma x=0$. I have found a solution that works for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ using undetermined coefficients.

---

The complementary solution $x_c$ is the solution to the equation $4t^2x_c''+x_c=0$, which is $x_c=c_1\sqrt t+c_2\sqrt t\ln t$. Now we may guess that a particular solution takes the form $x_p=\sum\limits_{i=0}^n A_it^i$ where $A_i$ is some constant. This sum encompasses all linearly independent derivatives of $at^n$. Then this solution must satisfy:
$$4t^2\sum_{i=0}^ni(i-1)A_it^{i-2}+\sum_{i=0}^nA_it^i=at^n$$
We can simplify this sum:
$$\sum_{i=0}^n4i(i-1)A_it^i+\sum_{i=0}^nA_it^i=at^n$$
$$\sum_{i=0}^nA_it^i\big(4i(i-1)+1\big)=at^n$$
$$\big(4n(n-1)+1\big)A_nt^n+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}A_it^i\big(4i(i-1)+1\big)=at^n$$
From this, we see that $A_i=0$ for all $i\neq n$ since all powers of $t$ are linearly independent from each other, so we are left with the equation:
$$(4n^2-4n+1)A_nt^n=at^n$$
Solving for $A_n$ we find that $$A_n=\frac{a}{4t^2-4t+1}=\frac{a}{(2t-1)^2},$$
and therefore the solution to the differential equation is
$$x=c_1\sqrt t+c_2\sqrt t\ln t+\frac{at^n}{(2n-1)^2}$$
for all natural numbers $n$.

---

I found this solution rather surprising simply because the particular solution was proportional to $t^n$. However, this solution is only guaranteed to work for $n\in\mathbb{N}$. In particular, it obviously will not work for $n=\frac{1}{2}$. I would like to see other solutions to this differential equation that work more broadly for real $n$, and particularly for $n=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: It actually works for all n. Just forget what you did and suppose someone gives you x = at^n/(2n-1)^2 where n is a real number (which is not 0.5). Then checking directly we see it satisfies the DE, right?

Comment: @DesmondMiles true. But how do we go about finding the solution when $n=\frac{1}{2}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this using variation of parameters. In this case, you will look for a solution $y_p = u(t)\sqrt{t}+v(t)\sqrt{t}\log t$ that solves the nonhomogeneous equation for $n=1/2$. There are explicit formulas for $u$ and $v$, which you can find here: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/VariationofParameters.aspx

In this case, you get $u=0$ and $v = (a\log t)/8$, so your particular solution would be $y_p = \frac{a\sqrt{t}\log^2t}{8}$